# Documentation for creation of .display files for Google Cloud offering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-marketplace

I am creating a listing/offer for Google Cloud platform marketplace, which contains a schema and a display file for UI. However, I am struggling to find the documentation regarding various components like disk, input fields, network etc. which can guide regarding various types and the restriction I can have.

Like for network selection we have following resource:

```
  network:
    type: array
    default: [default]
    minItems: 1
    maxItems: 1
    x-googleProperty:
      type: GCE_NETWORK
      gceNetwork:
        allowSharedVpcs: True
        machineTypeProperty: machineType
```

But I could not get a documentation to find various options available and their usage?

Can someone help me to find appropriate docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/develop)?

Comment: No, I have updated question to include example

Comment: DeploymentSpec in configurations.yaml might be help you on this issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/marketplace-tools/blob/42c92e93416ebba46cebc2926b572af5516e612b/examples/deployment-manager/autogen/singlevm/configurations.yaml#L95